# Comparing RGB image pixel values with a threshold. Using .channels,.depth with a Scalar does not give error in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to compare the difference between two image blocks with a threshold. Following is the code :

```
int main()
{ 
 // Reading images
 Mat image = imread("/home/folder/00000001.png",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
 Mat a_image = imread("/home/folder/00000011.png",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
   int imsize=image.rows*image.cols;  // total num of pixels
   int block_size=16; // have to divide image in blocks of 16*16
   div_t result_r;
   result_r=div(image.rows,block_size);
    if(result_r.rem!=0)
    {
     cout<<"\n number of rows should be multiple of block size";
     return 1;
    }
   div_t result_c;
   result_c=div(image.cols,block_size);
   if(result_c.rem!=0)
    {
     cout<<"\n number of columns should be multiple of block size";
     return 1;
    }
   Scalar img_mean;Scalar a_img_mean;  // variables that will store mean intensity values of RGB 16*16 blocks
        Scalar diff_mean; // difference between mean values of both the images
        Scalar th=Scalar::all(0.02); 
 // threshold vector [0.2,0.2,0.2] with which the above difference values have to be compared i.e. each difference value for B channel to be compared with first entry in Scalar th i.e. 0.2 , similarly all values of G with 2nd entry in th ...

cout<<th[0];cout<<"--th \n";

    Mat img; Mat a_img;
    image.copyTo(img);
    a_image.copyTo(a_img);

    for(int y = 0; y <img.rows-1;y+=block_size)
    {
      for(int x = 0; x < img.cols-1;x+=block_size)
      {    
        Mat imgblock = img(Rect(x, y, block_size, block_size)); // selecting one block of 16*16
    Mat a_imgblock = a_img(Rect(x, y, block_size, block_size));
        img_mean=mean(imgblock); //taking mean of intensities
    a_img_mean=mean(a_imgblock);
        absdiff(img_mean,a_img_mean,diff_mean); // finding difference between intensities of both images img and a_img

    Mat match;  // Mat having 0 or 255 depending on the condition for comparison
    compare(diff_mean,th,match,CMP_GE);
    cout<<diff_mean.type;
          }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I have messed up the data types between Scalar and Mat,the line

```
cout<<diff_mean.type;
```

prints 30 repeatedly.

Moreover

```
cout << match
```

prints vectors of 4 dimensions, so the compare function is not comparing the difference values channel wise.

Can anybody please suggest me the correction ? I cant figure out how should i compare each channel with a single threshold value without using for loops.

Comment: What is your expected output for diff_mean = Scalar(0.4, 0.1, 0.1) and th = Scalar(0.2, 0.2, 0.2)?

Comment: The expected output should just tell me whether 0.4 of B channel is greater than 0.2 of th, 0.1 is less than 0.2 of second channel and so on. So the output should be Scalar(255,0,0) or Mat [255,0,0] in your example according to function 'compare'.